# Optimizing Draw Method in Java

Tags: java, optimization, graphics, drawing

I have a mandlebrot program that draws mandlebrot fractals to the screen. I have a timer that shows the speed of the calculation, which ranges from 0 - 10 ms. I have a draw(Graphics2D g) method that draws a 2 dimensional array of pixels to the screen. The timer shows that the draw method takes about 100 ms, and as zoom increases, gradually increases to about 700 ms. The draw method is continuously called, while the mandlebrot calculation method is only called when the mandlebrot is moved or zoomed in. Heres my code for the draw method:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    // col and row pixel positions of the pixel being drawn
    // The if statements check if the point is in the mandlebrot set
    // I added a 3 dimensional array just so it could store the color number, and 0 or 1 if it's in the mandlebrot set
    // g.drawLine() draws the pixel at it's location

    for(int col = 0; col < 640; col++) {
        for(int row = 0; row < 480; row++) {
            if(Mandlebrot.pixels[col][row][0] == 1) {
                g.setColor(new Color(Mandlebrot.pixels[col][row][1]));
                g.drawLine(col, row, col, row);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawLine(col, row, col, row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that maybe a BufferedImage would be faster, but when I tried it, I got some weird screen gltiches. I'm also thinking about trying to have multiple threads each render a portion of the screen at the same time. So maybe 1 thread draws pixels from (0,0) to (100,100) and another draws pixels from (0,100) to (100,200), and so on. Is there a better way to do this, and is the lag for sure being caused by the draw method? Or is there something else that hindering it? When the calculation method is called, the program starts about 10 threads to calculate portions of the screen, which increases performance quit a bit. The threads terminate when they finish.

Heres a runnable jar of the current program:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/uh93231z71q27y1/Mandlebrot.jar

Comment: It might be better to generate a `BufferedImage` of the current zoom level and simply paint that instead.  Painting can occur for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control.  Sometimes, it's just better to design and use your own buffer, especially for something that won't change over time (ie at the current zoom level), but which is time consuming and complex to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawline method is fairly expensive, it would be better to use a BufferedImage, and call

```
image.setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)
```

for all the pixels you need to draw

**EDIT:** As someone wanted to see metrics for what I have said, this is the times taken from an application I made where my code was doing something very similar (looping through an array representing pixels, and drawing each pixel with a colour). Each timing is in milliseconds using System.currentTimeMillis();

With graphics.drawLine:

```
Time : 71
Time : 66
Time : 71
Time : 66
Time : 68
Time : 66
Time : 68
Time : 68
Time : 69
Time : 65
Time : 67
Time : 68
Time : 75
```

with image.setRGB:

```
Time : 58
Time : 44
Time : 43
Time : 41
Time : 45
Time : 45
Time : 45
Time : 45
Time : 44
Time : 45
Time : 46
Time : 45
Time : 45
```

Comment: Really, do you have metrics for that?

Comment: Not formally but this is similar to something I created before, and it was noticeably faster using the setRGB method rather than drawLine for setting the colour of individual pixels

Comment: You might want to also post the code you used to generate the metrics ;)

Comment: I would, but I have a feeling this is a homework assignment, since I did pretty much exactly the same assignment last year!